# How do I quickly convert audio-files into spectrogram in Python?

Tags: multithreading, machine-learning, spectrogram

I am trying to do this thing where I take a bunch of short audio clips and convert them into spectrograms. I'm reading the audio files from a folder with roughly 8,000 files. Here is what I did:

```
import os 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
import pathlib
import cv2

path = os.path.abspath('wav')

for file in os.listdir(path): 
    filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
    if pathlib.Path(filepath).suffix == '.png':
        continue

     samplingFreq, signalData = wavfile.read(filepath)
     Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(signalData, 
     Fs=samplingFreq,NFFT=1024, cmap = 'binary')
     plt.axis('off')

     s = filepath
     s = s[:s.rfind(".")] + ".png"
     plt.savefig(s, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
     os.remove(filepath)
```

The issue is that this is taking literally forever. I have gone through about 1/8 of the images within the past few hours. I'm essentially just opening each file from my folder, converting it into a spectrogram, then removing the audio file. I do not have enough knowledge with how threads work in order to utilize them effectively. Can someone give me some pointers on how to do this more efficiently? Or how I can change my code?

Comment: You can probably get a decent speedup without fiddling with threads in python. Just split the files into groups - one per core on your machine - and run one loop over each group in a separate shell background process.   Should be about 5 minutes to set that up.

Comment: Gene, I noticed that initially it does run fairly quickly but it slows down. I don't have a CS background, so I don't know why, but I'm assuming it has something to do with how memory is being allocated. How exactly would I "split it into groups"? Would I have to put the files into a different folder?

Comment: Do you mean it runs fast on the first few files, then slows down?

Comment: Hey Gene, that is what I mean. I think for the first 10 or so minutes its going at 15-20 files/min and then it slows down to 3-4 files/min after ~30 minutes. Which makes me think that I should just split it into different folders and run more than 1 python script, but is that much different from just using more than one thread? So far, I've just been stopping then rerunning the script like an idiot :P